# Optimize decrementing maximum of uint8

Tags: c++, sse, micro-optimization

I found that my program spends most of its time in a loop similar to this:

```
uint8_t (&c) [17] = ...
for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
    if (c[x + 1] < c[x] - 1) {
        c[x + 1] = c[x] - 1;
    }
}
```

It calculates the field values as maximum of the current value and the previous field's value minus 1.

Is there any way to speed this up?

`c` is the result of several SSE operations, so it may be in an xmm already. However, any other kind of improvement is most welcome, too.

Comment: No idea if it would be faster, but have you tried [std::max](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max)?

Comment: @Steve I'm afraid that's not possible here, because I'm not looking for a single global maximum. Instead, each value in the array depends on the immediately previous value.

Comment: What code is currently being generated?

Comment: The dependency on the previous value prevents this operation from really being parallelizable, which makes this a particularly tricky optimization problem. I'd have to think about it some more, but maybe you can introduce a second vector, initialize that with the previous field's value minus one, and then use `PMAXUB` on the two vectors to get the maximum. I'm not sure, though, if once you paid the overhead of setting that up, it would actually come out faster than your current code. How slow *is* your current code? What kind of performance target are we shooting for?

Comment: @mafu I mean inside your loop - `c[x + 1] = std::max(c[x + 1], c[x] - 1)`. Probably not much different than what you're already doing, though.

Comment: Steve is on the right track here. The compiler is almost certainly generating branching code for your `if` statement, and mispredicted branches are extremely slow. Whether `std::max` will be an improvement or not depends on how your compiler optimizes it, but a single assignment using the conditional operator (`c[x + 1] = (c[x + 1] < c[x] - 1) ? (c[x] - 1) : c[x + 1];`) will almost certainly be transformed into a conditional move (or other equivalent branchless code) by the compiler, which would make a significant difference if the condition is not predictable.

Comment: See [here](https://godbolt.org/g/F4K05h) for a demonstration. ICC generates identical code for both versions, owing to its advanced optimizer. GCC and Clang don't: although they smartly unroll the loop, they do generate branching code for the `if` statement. With the conditional operator, they'll use a conditional move. Again, whether you really see a performance improvement from this depends on how unpredictable the condition is. I thought about posting it as an answer, but I'm still waiting on some indication of what the performance target is.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I will try `std:max` and post the results as well as the asm soon.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't have a specific target. This kind of loop takes about 80% of the total runtime, so anything would be useful, I guess.

Comment: I replaced the `if` with `max` and found that performance doubled.

Comment: Interestingly, `max` was consistently slightly faster than a trinary assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependency can be broken by noticing how the result is the maximum of sixteen separate kernels, each of form `0 0 0 0 N N-1 N-2 N-3 N-3`.

```
__m128i d = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&c);  // get 16 bytes
__m128i ramp = _mm_set_epi8(15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0);
static __m128i bcast[16]; // shuffles item at i to i+1, i+2, ... 15
// e.g. bcast[3] = _mm_set_epi8(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0xff,0xff,0xff);

for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    __m128i tmp = _mm_shuffle_epi8(d, bcast[i]);
    tmp = _mm_subs_epu8(tmp, ramp);  // saturated subtraction
    ramp = _mm_srli_si128(ramp, 1);        // Shift the ramp
    d = _mm_max_epu8(d, tmp);
}
```

The resulting dependency from `d = max(d, x[i])` is actually independent of order (given that ramp_i doesn't have to be evaluated incrementally) and the dependency chain can be collapsed to a binary tree.

But we can do better than 16 iterations -- a divide and conquer technique would split the task to lower and upper half, each requiring 8 iterations (and possible to do in parallel). Then one needs one final stage of merge, where one has to merge the upper result d[8..15] with the decreasing tail of d[0..7].

Comment: I've thought about this for a bit more and believe I now understand your ideas. I'll try to build the SSE code and see how far it goes.